# When you change ships does your old one disappear?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I found a ship from a distress signal and misunderstood the inventory prompts when switching to it so all of my old ships inventory is still on the old ship. I have no idea where I left it but I just want to know if it is worth searching for it at all? Will it still be in the same place and will it have everything it had in it before the switch?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you set your ship down right next to a crashed one (so you can easily find your ship again), then you can claim ownership of the crashed ship, scrap all of its parts for valuable elements, and walk over and reclaim ownership of your original ship.  You won't lose *anything*.

The game seems to do a good job of remembering the state of things (e.g. which boxes have been opened, which houseplants have been farmed, etc.) even very far away from one's current position, but I don't know what its limits are, and I would be very surprised if it remembers that info after the game has been shut off.

**Terrifying Update**

I recently made my first multi-million unit ship purchase inside a space station.  My old ship was still sitting where it had been when the purchase was complete, and as I'd not been able to fit all of my inventory into the new ship, I decided to use the above tactic to go grab the rest.  When I reclaimed my old ship, grabbed the remaining items, and turned around ... my new ship was *gone*.  My heart stopped for several beats until I realized that the game had *moved* it to a different landing pad.  (It had been parked behind my old ship and now it was to the right of my old ship.)

So, I don't know how safe it is in general to immediately reclaim your old ship after you buy a new one.  (But I still regularly use this approach on crashed ships.)

Comment: Actually, I've been visiting the same space station a couple of times, and it would only let me farm the houseplants in there on my first visit - even after shutting the game down in between. I haven't left the star system yet though, not sure if that would make the game forget. Even then, that is pretty impressive.

Comment: @Andii Neat! I've had both of these experiencies: (a) I return to an outpost after leaving the planet and shutting down the game, and it remembers that I opened the Pu boxes by the landing pad. (b) I return to a space station after visiting two planets (no shutdown) and I can do the meet/greet dialog with the station manager again (i.e. not the one you have to pay 20C for, but the initial one where you have to guess what he's talking about).  Also, on most space stations I've been able to farm the suit upgrade station at least twice (I haven't tried for more than twice).

Comment: The game seems to keep a memory file for each planet. I've seen many pictures of people who dig a tunnel through rock using the Plasma Grenade, turn off the game, then when they log back on the game has spawned flora/fauna into that new hole.

Comment: I just got shocked as well. Crash site. Claiming new ship to dismantle components. Claiming back old ship. GAME CRASHES. Re-Starting and I got the old ship. The new one is gone! What a luck the game has also the previous savegame available, which was saved when I exited my actual ship.

Comment: The entire game is online-based, including discoveries and harvested materials, so everything is saved on the game's servers. Therefore, if you leave a ship on a planet, it will remain there until a player claims it. However, a ship left in a space station will disappear if you go too far away or if you are away from the station at all for a long period of time. It will also usually disappear as soon as you log off.

Answer (score 6):

Similar to upgrading a multi-tool you lose the old one but can pull whatever attachments over at the compare screen.

Made the mistake of not transferring the first time and lost some good stuff.

Comment: Best bet is to trade for a new ship with more slots either by buying one from someone in a space station or at a ship dock on a planet.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the accepted answer is correct.

When I was tearing apart the upgrades on my old ship I accidentally discarded a stack of much needed Zinc.
No problem, I thought, I'll just reload my last save.
After I reloaded my last save, my old ship was no where to be found.

So if you have reloaded since you transferred ships, I don't think you are going to find your old one anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

There's currently a glitch with claiming ships (2.06C) where you can lose access to your current starship if it has any movable items left in its inventory when you swap.  Just make sure you empty it to your exosuit and freighter before hand.