# Can you lose your Pre-Order ship?

Tags: no-mans-sky

No Man's Sky offers exclusive ships to players who pre-ordered the game (in my Case the Horizon Omega, since I have the Steam version). As discussed in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/281533/when-you-change-ships-does-your-old-one-disappear), you can only have one ship at a time as your old one disappears when you get a new one.

This made me kind of afraid of actually redeeming my pre-order ship. What happens if I start using it, and then decide to buy another one? Will my pre-order ship disappear forever, or will I be able to redeem it again / get it back another way? If it's really exclusive to pre-orders, it'd be a shame to lose it.

Comment: I've added a new answer to your linked question: your old ship does not disappear when claiming a crashed one.  However, I'm not sure about when you buy (or "redeem") a new ship.  Certainly your old multi-tool does disappear when you buy a new one.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about not being able to get the ship back. It's definitely worth giving it up for more inventory space.

Comment: @Kat It's more about the fact that it's a unique ship exclusive to preorders, which I wouldn't like to lose forever even after finding a better one.

Comment: @Andii it's worth redeeming just so that you can get out of your starting star system earlier. You won't have to craft a hyperdrive, for example, so it gets you out and exploring the universe faster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just brought a new ship, I can't redeem it again, so once a it's gone, it's gone.

Comment: Would you happen to know if it becomes available again if you start the game over? If it doesn't, I'd probably never want use it...

Comment: @Andii you can claim it once per play through, play through meaning from when you crashed